# Multiplying two dimensional Array lists

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm learning ArrayLists. All I'm trying to do is to multiply two different ArrayLists. Given below is the code. The code generates one ArrayList from user input and the second ArrayList is given in the code.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prog3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the number of rows ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                array.get(i).add(sc.nextInt());
            }
        }
        Iterator it = array.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arr = new
                ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        arr.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        arr.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

        arr.get(0).add(5);
        arr.get(0).add(4);
        arr.get(1).add(7);
        arr.get(1).add(8);
        Iterator it2 = arr.iterator();
        while (it2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it2.next());
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < array.size(); r++) {
            for (int h = 0; h < arr.size(); h++) {

                System.out.println(r * h);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it's not working? Please explain the error you are getting.

Comment: @WonderWorld I'm able to  run the program ..however,i'm not getting the expected result.I'm not getting any compile time or run time error.The only Error that i'm facing here is the fact that i'm not able to print the product.

Comment: As answered, you are multiplying the indexes of the nested for loops.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question, just sharing some good practices that I hope will save you from writing a lot of bad code in the future. You have two ArrayLists in your code, one is named `array` and the other is named `arr`. The good practice _generally_ is not to name your variables based on what data structure is referenced by that variable, but rather based on what is the data stored in that data structure. (Comment too long, split in two)

Comment: @mohan babu Not sure but maybe `System.out.println(array.get(r).get(r) * arr.get(h).get(h));` gives the wanted result? I tested it, but i'm getting dizzy with all those arraylists

Comment: How is `array` different from `arr`? One holds the user input, and the other holds some predefined data. Then it would be much more explicit to name your variables `userInput` and `predefinedData`. And if that data is supposed to model something in the real world, say the number of fruits in baskets, then it is even better to name the variable `fruitsInBaskets`! Code is written for programmers, not for computers, and the identifiers (method names and variables) should describe _what_ it does, not _how_ it does that.

Comment: Also, look, there is no actual _question_ in your question, i.e. no sentence that asks for something with a question mark in the end : ) Now you're basically trying to have people read your code and find something that is fishy there. You did not state any issues you're dealing with, didn't say what is your expected result and what is the actual result you're getting. That is not how questions should be asked. You just got lucky people made some effort to guess what you need. But generally no one should guess your issues when you're asking a question, so next time please be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code multiplies every `Integer` element in your `array` times every element in your `arr`. Although your question is not completely clear with regard to expected output, at least this should give you a hint of what to do.

```
    for (int r = 0; r < array.size(); r++) {
        for (int h = 0; h < arr.size(); h++) {
            System.out.println(":array.get(" + r + ") * arr.get(" + h + "):");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.get(r).size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.get(h).size(); j++) {
                    int n1 = array.get(r).get(i);
                    int n2 = arr.get(h).get(j);
                    System.out.println(n1 + " * " + n2 + " = " + (n1 * n2));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are multiplying the indexes r and h, not the list elements indexed by r and h. This is your problem here. Fix that and you'll get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the answer finally..below posted is my code.

```
  int r=0,k=0;
  int sum = 0;
    while((r < array.size()) &&(k < arr.size())) {
        int i=0,o = 0;
        int u=0;
        while((i < array.get(r).size())&&(o < arr.get(k).size()) ) {

            int s = array.get(r).get(i);
            int  e = arr.get(k).get(o);
            sum = sum + (s*e);


            i = i + 1;
            o=o+1;
        }



        r++;
        k++;
    }

  System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```